# awk sum numbers after a separator

Tags: awk

I need a simple awk to calculate the sum of the number at the end of a file which looks like this:

```
/z02/ABCD/stuff/ABC_DEF_02/count/ABC_DEF_02_ABCDE66.log.20120605_101201_015.log.gz:28
/z02/ABCD/stuff/ABC_DEF_02/count/ABC_DEF_02_ABCDE66.log.20120605_101202_015.log.gz:28
/z02/ABCD/stuff/ABC_DEF_02/count/ABC_DEF_02_ABCDE66.log.20120605_101203_015.log.gz:28
/z02/ABCD/stuff/ABC_DEF_02/count/ABC_DEF_02_ABCDE66.log.20120605_101204_015.log.gz:28
```

so basically the numbers after the ":" need to be added together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "....." | awk '-F:' '{total+=$NF}END{print "sumTotal=" total}'
```

You can, of course, leave out the "sumTotal=" part, depending on your needs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: tnx to @brandizzi for fixing fixing a keyboard bobble in my original post. Good luck to all.

Comment: @JaypalSingh : Hey man, where you been? You must have a good contract. I'll be dropping off the radar pretty soon, as I finally landed a new fulltime job. whoop-eee! Good luck to all!

Comment: I know .. been off the radar, moved from Calgary, AB to Tampa, FL. Working on several assignments so been busy with that. How have you been? Congratulations on the new job. Wishing you the best! :)